# Breaking MT19937 with 1-bit numbers

Tags: python, random, ctf

I'm working on breaking python `random module`. By using `mt19937predictor, randcrack, extend-mt19937-predictor`, I can easily predict the correct number generated by random module, but those tools only accept 32-bit numbers or multiply of 32 (64, 256, etc.) What if I have some smaller numbers, like 8-bit numbers or 1-bit numbers? The given data will always be bigger than 19937 bits to return the initial state of the `MT19937`.

Comment: What's the point of this?  The MT19937 algorithm has a sturdy theoretical basis.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm trying to correctly predict every single value from random.getrandbits() as part of a ctf challenge. If given 624 32-bit numbers `(624 * 32 =19968 > 19937)` , those tools can easily predict next values, but what if I got 19968 1-bit numbers instead? I kinda got stuck there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's really a cryptanalysis question that belongs on the [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk No it doesn't; mt19937 is not a cryptographically secure RNG.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: That doesn't matter, the techniques of cryptanalysis are what is used to "break" the RNG in this context.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Are you really telling me that you know the OT of cryptography better than me, a 3 year moderator and top 3 user on the site?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: It's clearly on-topic there, and it says so right in the [help center](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). There are numerous similar questions on the site.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Maybe you should not stop reading and get to the point where it says "Cryptographically secure (pseudo-)random number generation and entropy;". Do you think this is the first question about Mersenne Twister that is handled on the site?

Comment: @LilLee Generally we don't **skip** bits when asking bits, bytes or words from a random number generator. So sticking everything together might work. Beware of issues with big / little endian though, you may need to reverse bytes, words or both. If just one bit of every word is taken then it becomes a different issue. This bit of context is missing from the question.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I guess you just didn't read the question. Or the title.